# Android Read from Settings.Global from API < 17?

Tags: android, settings

Edit per the answer below I changed manifest to :

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
```

Created method:

```
@TargetApi(17)
private static boolean isAirplaneModeOn17(Context context) {
   return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
}
```

However I'm still getting "Settings.Global cannot be resolved or is not a field" when I clean the project.  Ideas?

---

I have an app where I read airplane mode state using the following code:

```
return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
```

This works great for all my GB and <= 4.1x uses.

Of course, in API 17 Settings.Global was introduced and this location has changed.

```
return boolean airmode = Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) != 1;
```

Aside from the fact there could be workarounds to get airplane mode state in API17, the real question is how does one compile a project that supports both reading of Settings.System and Settings.Global from the same project?

I can't seem to be able to make Eclipse "ignore" that "Settings.Global cannot be resolved or is not a field" when the project build target is set to anything other than 4.2 API 17.  I know the code will work for my 4.2 users, and have that designation setup as follows:

```
private static boolean isAirplaneModeOn(Context context) {
    if (apiVersion < 17) {
       return Settings.System.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
    } else {
       return Settings.Global.getInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0) == 1;
    }
}
```

I've messed around with min and target API in the manifest and it doesn't seem to have any affect, Eclipse still will not compile my project.

FWIW, here's some pertinent version info:

ADK 21.0.0.v201210310015-519525

Eclipse Version: 4.2.1 Build id: M20120914-1800

TIA!

Comment: Right click on your project, click Properties and then click on Android, is Android 4.2 checked?

Comment: @A--C Doh! Forgot that thx. Yes that worked, can you post this as an answer, I can accept if you want.  Unfortunately this opens a big can-o-worms I guess, wonder what else will break in my project build and target API jumping up a few ... :(

Comment: Hopefully as little as possible!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on your project, click Properties and then click on Android, check off Android 4.2, Eclipse will then load everything that is needed by 4.2 and everything should compile.